# VUE 2: Dont use a component if an object is null

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am currently having a problem: I need to use a component only if the source information is available, else don't use it. I have tried with `v-if` but it appears to call the component anyway.

```js
<div v-if="entry.banners">
   <banner-selector
      v-for="banner in entry.banners"
      :key="banner.id"
      :banner-id="banner.id"
      :autotarget="banner.autotarget" :promo-selected="promoSelected"
      @selectedItem="updateItemSelected($event)" />
    <banner-base
      v-for="banner in entry.banners"
       :key="banner.id"
       :slug-ficha="slugSelected"
       :promo-selected="promoSelected" 
       :banner-id="banner.id" />
</div>
```

This gives me an error because `id` doesn't exist when `entry.banners` is `null`. Also I am declaring `banner-selector` and `banner-base`, but they won't be used when the `entry.banners` object is `null`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

just put the below condition in the div:

```
 v-if="entry && entry.banners && entry.banners.length"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing `entry.banners !== null`, but have in mind that (I have no idea what could happen) if `entry.banners` is an empty object instead of `null`.

So other solution could be to create a `computed` property and do that check inside the computed property (both null or empty) and done.

I am aware that maybe there is a better solution, but these are the solutions I can share with you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure [entry.banners](/questions/tagged/entry.banners) is [null](/questions/tagged/null)? [null](/questions/tagged/null) is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so probably the problem is elsewhere.

Maybe you have some empty banner object that is causing the problem. In this case I would log the the [entry.banners](/questions/tagged/entry.banners) when the component is created and mounted and check what data is inside.